# My Button is not loading a new page and I cannot figure out why

Tags: angular

I've set up the routing fine and I can load the pages up via the address bar, however when I try to access them via a onClick button, nothing loads. When I set them up as a Component however they do show up so the information is there

Button:

```
 <div class="content">
      <button _ngcontent-c2="" class="raiys-primary-button" type="submit" onclick="next()">
        Next
        <div _ngcontent-c2="" class="ripple-container"></div>
    </button>
    </div>
```

Typescript class:

```
 next(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/next-page');
  }
```

Stackblitz code

https://angular-ivy-trdt3q.stackblitz.io

Comment: Have you added a <router-outlet> that will render the page? More on it [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

Comment: Yes, the pages do render fine and as far as I can tell the <router-outlet> is set up fine (the rest of the site doesn't have this issue, just on new pages)

Comment: We'll most certainly need more code in order to debug this. If possible even a Stackblitz/Codepen. The implementation here looks fine.

Comment: I can do that, gimme a few mins, I'll add it to the main comment

Comment: I think the stackblitz link is wrong, i could only access using this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-trdt3q . And in that stackblitz you are missing arouting-module aswell as router-outlet, on top of that you have a button in the app-component with a click-event calling "next()" that isnt defined.

Comment: It's (click)="next()" not onClick like in react :)

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you need to use (click)="yourFunction()" notation instead of the normal JavaScript "onClick".

-> https://angular.io/guide/event-binding